# Adding two linked lists from the end [ DUPLICATE]

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have two linked lists, where each node contains a single digit. The digits are in reverse order, such that 1's digit is at the head of the list. I have to write a function that adds up the two numbers and returns the sum. 
I have seen many solutions over the internet and came up with my own solution.I want to know if converting the digits to a string using StringBuilder is an efficient way of doing this.

```
public int addlists(Node head,Node head2) {
    int sum = 0;
    Node n = head;
    Node n2 = head2;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
    while(n!=null) {
        s.append(n.data);
        n = n.next;
    }

    while(n2!=null) {
        s2.append(n2.data);
         n2 = n2.next;
    }

    s.reverse(); s2.reverse();

    sum = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(s2.toString());
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You marked your question as duplicated ?

Comment: Did you add [DUPLICATE] manually to the question title?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `StringBuilder`, you can do this using simple math, just keep track of `carry` being generated, and multiply ten's place by 10 and hundred's place by 100 using `Math.pow`

```
public int addTwoLists(Node first, Node second) {
    int carry=0,sum=0,k=0;

    while (first != null || second != null){

        sum = sum + ((carry+(first!=null?first.data:0)+(second!=null?second.data:0))%10) * ((int)(Math.pow(10,k)));

        carry=(carry+(first!=null?first.data:0)+(second!=null?second.data:0)>=10)?1:0;

        k++;
        if (first != null) { first = first.next; }
        if (second != null) { second = second.next; }
    }
    return sum;
}
```